# jQuery : add attr to each element based on values list

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code for add `attr` to option element that have defined value on `index` variable:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('option').each(function() {
      var index = '1';
      if($(this).attr('value') == index)
        $(this).attr('selected','selected');
    });

});
```

How can add attr to each element that have value listed on `index` variable. Something like this:

```
      var index = '1,2,5,8,7,9';
      if($(this).attr('value') == index)
...
```

UPDATE:
This is my html code:

```
<select name="category[]" multiple="multiple" id="category">
    <option class="level-0" value="1">Jobs</option>
    <option class="level-1" value="24">CSS</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="5">Products</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#category option').each(function() {
  var index = [1,2,5,8,7,9],
      value = parseInt( this.value, 10); // convert the value to integer
  if($.inArray(value, index) >= 0)
    $(this).attr('selected','selected'); //or, $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WgNG9/2/)***

---

## Without array

```
$('#category option').each(function() {
  var index = '1,2,5,8,7,9',
      value = this.value;
  if(index.indexOf(value) >= 0)
    $(this).attr('selected','selected'); //or, $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WgNG9/3/)***

---

## Using `filter()`

```
var index = '1,2,5,8,7,9';
$('#category option').filter(function() {
  return index.indexOf(this.value) >= 0;
}).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WgNG9/5/)***

---

## Using `.attr('selected', callback)`

```
var index = '1,2,5,8,7,9';
$('#category option').attr('selected', function(i, val) {
  if( index.indexOf( this.value) >= 0 )
  return 'selected';
})
```

***[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WgNG9/9/)***

Comment: Nice answer, lots of different options. The string one (and its various derivatives, consequently) doesn't quite work though, since a number can easily be a substring of another number -- for example `70` contains `7`, so this would pass for both of them, even if only `70` was in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the values into an array, then use the native js array `indexOf` method:

```
var index = [1,2,5,8,7,9];
if( index.indexOf( $(this).val() ) > -1) {
    //...
}
```

---

To do this for multiple elements you would use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var index = [1,2,5,8,7,9];
$("#category option").each( function() {
    if( index.indexOf( $(this).val() ) > -1) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not iterate over the `option`s

```
$("select").each(function(){
  var index = $(this).val();
  if($.inArray([1,2,5,8,7,9], index) > -1)
     $(this).prop("selectedIndex", index);  //set selected index
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `select`, you could do much simpler by using jQuery.

You could just do:

```
$("#select-id").val(value);  
// eg: $("#select-id").val('5'); will make the option whose value is 5 to be selected.
```

***[Check the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/PbnGz/)***

Comment: @NuLLeR Check the demo I added.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a quick solution with your current setup with `index` as a comma separated string, try this:

```
$(this).prop('selected', 
  (new RegExp('('+index.split(',').join('|')+')'))
    .test(this.value)
);
```